# Installing Dependency for epel from yum update on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, python

I think that I'm not quite understanding where epel repo reads dependency for a python update. For example when I run `sudo yum update` I get the below and then successfully run `pip install requests` and `pip install six` to satisfy dependencies listed but still getting same message about dependencies. I can also see the requests and six packages in my `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` folder and also can import in python without any issues.

## epel from my CentOS-Base.repo file:

```
[epel]
name = none
baseurl = http://mirror.rightscale.com/epel/6/x86_64/archive/20140514/
  http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/epel/6/x86_64/archive/20140514/
  http://ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com/epel/6/x86_64/archive/20140514/
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.rightscale.com
 * centosplus: mirror.rightscale.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.rightscale.com
 * rightscale-epel: mirror.rightscale.com
 * updates: mirror.rightscale.com
rightscale-epel                                                                                                                                                                                                        |  951 B     00:00
repo id                                                                                               repo name                                                                                                                         status
base                                                                                                  none                                                                                                                               6,367
centosplus                                                                                            none                                                                                                                                  48
epel                                                                                                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                                    11,830
extras                                                                                                none                                                                                                                                  14
jenkins                                                                                               Jenkins                                                                                                                              314
percona                                                                                               CentOS 6 - Percona                                                                                                                   671
puppetlabs-deps                                                                                       Puppet Labs Dependencies El 6 - x86_64                                                                                                77
puppetlabs-products                                                                                   Puppet Labs Products El 6 - x86_64                                                                                                   538
rightscale-epel                                                                                       none                                                                                                                                 285
updates                                                                                               none                                                                                                                                 909
repolist: 21,053
```

Even manually trying `rpm -ivh python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm` produces:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    python-requests is needed by python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
    python-rsa is needed by python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
    python-six is needed by python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch

# sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com
 * centosplus: ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com
 * rightscale-epel: ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com
 * updates: ec2-us-west-mirror.rightscale.com
rightscale-epel                                                                                |  951 B     00:00
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libunwind.x86_64 0:1.1-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package libunwind.x86_64 0:1.1-3.el6 will be an update
---> Package python-boto.noarch 0:2.27.0-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-boto.noarch 0:2.38.0-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python-six for package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-rsa for package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-requests for package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Package python-pip.noarch 0:1.3.1-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-pip.noarch 0:7.1.0-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package ssmtp.x86_64 0:2.61-21.el6 will be updated
---> Package ssmtp.x86_64 0:2.61-22.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-boto.noarch 0:2.38.0-1.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python-six for package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-requests for package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Package python-rsa.noarch 0:3.1.1-5.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-requests
Error: Package: python-boto-2.38.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-six
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual `pip` installs will in no way satisfy RPM dependencies, and may actually conflict (in the presence-of-files sense, not in any RPM sense) with vendor- or repository-supplied packages, depending on what got installed where. The dependencies are part of the RPM packages, and usually are collated into databases by e.g. `yum` and so forth.

A `yum install python-boto` works without failure on my RHEL6+EPEL test system, so I'm not sure what you've done that would cause your listed errors. Are you also using package repositories besides EPEL? I've definitely seen conflicts between packages for hosts that had both EPEL and other package repositories enabled, and have had to manually uninstall and reinstall packages to rectify install conflicts and errors stemming from such multiple-enabled-repository hosts (e.g. hosts with both EPEL and rpmfusion on them).

The manual `pip` install may also complicate matters; if I do `pip` installs, I do them to a home directory, or otherwise definitely not to any vendor space used by RPM.

Comment: yeah. pretty confused by this still. I was able to get change my epel configuration files to download the older boto version instead of 2.38 and that installed without any issues but I still don't understand how exactly epel operates in terms of older vs. newer packages. thinking I had an epel on my system (5?) that was incompatible with my current os python (2.6.6). But still not understanding how to upgrade my epel packages. How do I now update epel to use latest version of packages?

Comment: Usually just a `yum update` as per usual, unless things have somehow gone awry. Was the host upgraded from Centos 5? The usual solutions might be to fiddle with uninstalling and reinstalling packages, or if things are horribly awry, I usually re-KickStart-install the host...